# How can I show the computers operating system in C++?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am making an MFC dialog based application and its function is to read data from another project and the PC and copy this data to the clipboard. I already have the code that is needed to transfer the data from the external project, however I am a little stuck on how I am going to get the Operating System data and copy that data to the clipboard.

This is the code I have so far.

```
void CBugsDlg::OnBnClickedBtnCopy()
{
    CVersionTranslatomatic ver(::GetDesktopWindow());

    CString version = ver.GetMajorMinorVersionString() + " " + 
            ver.GetVersionType() + " " + ver.GetBuildNumber() + " " +
            ver.GetServicePack();

    HGLOBAL hglbCopy;

    if( OpenClipboard()){       
        EmptyClipboard();
        wchar_t *wcBuffer = 0;
        hglbCopy = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,
                (version.GetLength() + 1)*sizeof(wchar_t)); 
        wcBuffer = (wchar_t*)GlobalLock(hglbCopy);
        lstrcpy(wcBuffer, version);
        GlobalUnlock(hglbCopy);
        SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hglbCopy);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How much info do you need? You could always use the standard [`GetVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API, otherwise it's not 100% clear what you mean by `Operating System data` .. ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Operating System data". This isn't clear at all.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. By Operating System data I mean the Operating system the computer is running on for example "Windows 7 64-Bit".

Answer (score 1):

Using Window APIs You can fetch following OS Data-

1. OS Version (**OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi**)
2. OS system Info (**SYSTEM_INFO si**)

And I suppose following code will produce all the OS data you needed-

```
// Added the following two function pointers to support the below code
typedef void (WINAPI *PGETSYSTEMINFO)(LPSYSTEM_INFO);
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGETPRODUCTINFO)(DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, DWORD, PDWORD);

   OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
   SYSTEM_INFO si;
   PGETSYSTEMINFO pGetSystemInfo;
   PGETPRODUCTINFO pGetProductInfo;
   BOOL bOsVersionInfoEx;
   DWORD dwType;

   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));
   ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));

   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

   if( !(bOsVersionInfoEx = GetVersionEx ((OSVERSIONINFO *) &osvi)) )
      return 1;

   // Call GetNativeSystemInfo if supported or GetSystemInfo otherwise.

   pGetSystemInfo = (PGETSYSTEMINFO ) GetProcAddress(
      GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), 
      "GetNativeSystemInfo");
   if(NULL != pGetSystemInfo)
      pGetSystemInfo(&si);
   else GetSystemInfo(&si);
```

This code should easily be integrated with your MFC project.

Comment: [GetNativeSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx) is available on all supported Windows versions. No need for the function pointer mayhem and runtime linking. Simply call `GetNativeSystemInfo` and move on.